# Get type of value entered

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small piece of code where I need to get the typeof value entered. Right now, i am getting only value entered in the box, but not the typeof. Can anyone help me here?

```
<p id="res">Value</p><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>

<script>
    document.getElementById('fname').addEventListener('input', function(){
        document.getElementById('res').textContent= this.value;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `typeof` keyword, and if you want to test `number` vs `string` then you need to do a check type by using `isNaN` and `Number`

I changed your function to arrow function

```js
document.getElementById('fname').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const value = e.currentTarget.value;
  const checkType = isNaN(Number(value)) ? value : Number(value)
  document.getElementById('res').textContent = typeof checkType
})
```

```html
<p id="res">Value</p><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
```

Comment: But we can enter numbers also right

Comment: Thanks. It works. But when I transfer the same to R shiny (not sure if you are aware or not), this does not work ..  ````dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    HTML('<p id="res">Value</p><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>'),
    tags$script(
      "document.getElementById('fname').addEventListener('input', e => {
        document.getElementById('res').textContent= typeof e.currentTarget.value;});")````

Comment: you are not using my latest update on the answer, check the snippet carefully

Comment: No No. I used the one you did previously (i mean for only strings)

Comment: then I would say ask another question following this one and tag R shiny in specific , sorry I can't help you  with R shiny because I don't know it

Answer (score 0):

So typeof is not going to help you here. because the input is type="text" everthing typed into it will be casted to a string. exp: some types a 4, will be given to the js as "4". Im assuming you dont care about the type itself and just really want to know if they typed in a number. if thats the case, use the isNaN Function which will return false if a value can be casted to a number

`isNaN("4") //false isNaN("hello") //true`

PS: NaN stands for not a number